# Reserved error (-7776) ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access, oracle11g

tried to run below query with sql pass through query to connect to oracle

```
SELECT distinct sa.request_date  "RequestDate"
FROM xxx.yyyyyy   sa 
where to_char(sa.request_date, 'yyyy') = ‘2017’
--and rownum=1;
```

its fine when i put "and rownum=1" but when i ran the full query
i got below error:
[image]

please help, i have been busy with it for 3 days :(
Thanks!

Comment: It seems that, when you add the "and rownum =1" then MS Access able to handle the record because there is only one row, but when the SQL returns more than one row the MS Access won't handle it. If you could explain more about it then, we can help you.

Comment: @Vivek thanks, yes thats what happened. i even changed the parameter month to to_char(sa.request_date, 'mmyyyy') = ‘102017’, it works for only for that month, but when it tried different month, error pop up.  but when i ran it in plsql/sqldeveloper works ok

Comment: The first `and` should be `WHERE`, no? And no comma after `sa`.

Comment: sorry, yes it is 
SELECT distinct sa.request_date  "RequestDate"
FROM xxx.yyyyyy   sa

where to_char(sa.request_date, 'yyyy') = ‘2017’
--and rownum=1;

Comment: Can you remove the commented line and then try it once.

Comment: You have curly quotes around `2017`.  Perhaps that has something to do with the error.

Comment: Which Oracle/ODBC drivers do you use ?

Comment: I am pretty sure of what happens here: when you dont specify the rownum=1, it retrieve more rows and one or several of them have a corrupted `request_date` that can't be handled by Access or the Driver. The core issue is bad data, which leads to this second issue . Try to find the bad date, :proceed by dichotomy : `Rownum < 1000`, then `rownum < 100` and so on until you spot it

Comment: @Vivek i did result is still the same

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks, I changed it but same error

Comment: @ThomasG yes, we use driver 11g, i will try to do it, keep you posted.